# EVM issues with RF amplfier SKY66185-11

Tags: rf, power-amplifier

We have two PA's in a balanced config where the input RF signal comes into a directional coupler which acts like a splitter and then the output of the two PA's is combined by another directional coupler at the output end. We are using  Anaren X3C09P1 couplers. Please find attached block diagram of our PA setup.
[image]

We've been having EVM issues and upon inspection, we found that the 3.3V supply powering the PA's and other circuitry had a max current capacity of 700mA whereas the circuitry needed 1.035A. We replaced the regulator with a higher current version 1A as the 5V supply which supplies this regulator is maxed out at 1A.

We are still having issues despite being only 35mA short. Also, the regulator does not shutdown with the requirements of excessive current.

Also, We tried the circuit with only a single PA which drops the current requirement to 615mA but still got worse EVM.

EVM with single PA:
(20MHz = 5.8% at 24dBm; 10MHz = 6% at 24dBm; 5MHz = 10% at 24dBm)

EVM with two PA's:
(20MHz = 6.5% at 28dBm; 10MHz = 7% at 28dBm; 5MHz = 15% at 28dBm)

Expected EVM = 3.8~4.8% on all bandwidths.

Attached is the response from Skyworks on using single and dual PA's.
[image]
Any ideas of why a little less current leads to drastic changes in PA's EVM?

Comment: Hi, You said: "*Any ideas of why a little less current leads to drastic changes in PA's EVM?*" but you didn't explain what the "drastic changes" are (or did I miss it?). Also, are you saying that an EVM from Skyworks, has an underrated regulator for the current required by that EVM? If so, did you ask Skyworks why they seem to have fitted an underrated regulator? What did they say? If you didn't ask them, why not? They should know their EVM better than anyone else. And why are you using a 1A supply (and then a linear regulator) if you need 1.035A? Can you add details into the question? Thanks

Comment: Hi Sam, I have edited my post to reflect the EVM changes and expectations. No, Skyworks had nothing to do with the regulators. We just replaced our current power amplifer IC's(SKY65126-21) on the PA daughter board with SKY66185-11 IC's as the former is going obsolete.

Comment: The 3.3V  supplyon the daughter board (LM1963EST-3.3,1.5A) is being supplied by a 5V supply (LM2675) from our main board  through a picoblade header which can deliver a max current of 1A which is why we are limited to 1A in this case.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion now. You used "EVM" & from context, it *seemed* to be a "thing" so I assumed you meant an "evaluation module" which is often abbreviated to EVM (i.e. a self-contained module, usually from the manufacturer of the main device, so an EVM of that PA would come from Skyworks). Now I see you mean [error vector magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_vector_magnitude) measurements. Not what I thought you meant! The power supply configuration/wiring is still unclear to me (adding a block diagram would help) but I have to stop. Perhaps someone else will understand better.

Comment: Thanks, @SamGibson. Sorry,now I notice that I never abbreviated EVM as error vector magnitude. I have attached a block diagram which might help.